# What is the best language for creating RIM apps?

Tags: blackberry

We're interested in creating a game for RIM. What are the language options, pros and cons?

Comment: For BB phone or Playbook? An action game or a slow (cards, puzzle) game?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only get Java with Eclipse. Most mobile platforms only have one language you can program in.

I would consider using Javascript in the browser, but I'm not sure that blackberry's browser is fast enough for games.

Answer (score 1):

For the PlayBook the only current options are Adobe Air and WebDevelopment. C/C++ API has been announced for the sumer, as has the Android player.

For BlackBerries there is only the JDK (either using RIM's JDE, or their plugin for Eclipse), and WebDevelopment.

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/started/bbdevapproach.jsp